# how long will the fight between kalki and kali purush will last?

Tags: shiva, sanskrit, kali-yuga, vedic-gods, kalki

like how would a fight between kalki and kali purush look like? what kinds of attacks and technique they would use? and how long it will last? for days? for years? like for example the fight between Pandavas and Kauravas lasted for 18 days...